# WWW Local DataPath with umlauts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, external

I use a WWW request in my game to load external XML and JSON data. Everything works fine, except when running in StandAlone on a PC with an umlaut in the DataPath.

The users last name is "Rösner", data path is `file://C:/Users/Rösner/[GameDataPath...]`. The WWW Request returns an error:

```
WWW.error = "Couldn't open file /Users/Rösner/[GameDataPath...]"
WWW.bytesDownloaded = 0
WWW.message = ""
```

The path is correct, the file exists. It works as soon as we move the directory into another folder that's not located in `/Users/Rösner/`, for example an USB stick.

Is there any way to prevent this problem? The game will be released in Germany and we have quite a few last names with umlauts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `WWW` class instead of `System.IO`, you should escape your URI (["Note: URLs passed to WWW class must be '%' escaped."](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)).

Try:

```
var www=new WWW(WWW.EscapeURL(pathToYourFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard `System.IO` api:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath+"file.json");
```

It should be harder to break.

Comment: That will resolve in a new function for the specific case "use external files in standalone version" which I try to avoid. Is there no way to force the WWW request to use umlauts properly?

Comment: See other answer for a different approach.